# Run training container on Azure ML

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

i have 2 containers: 1 for training, 1 for prediction. The training container has been pushed in Azure Registry Containers (i built/pushed it with Docker, i tested it and it works perfectly in local)

The idea is to use Azure ML in order to run this container, but i have multiple problems:

First, each time i create a job, it doesn't connect with Azure Container Registry (where my train image is), even though i enabled the "admin" option:

[image: the error msg displayed]
[image: access keys of my registry container]

Secondly, i don't know on which "compute" object i should run my job, a cluster or an instance ? (i tried both, but i always have the problem mentioned earlier)

For context, i tried running the job with this code:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget
from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration
from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core import Experiment


ws = Workspace.from_config(path="./config.json")

env = Environment.from_docker_image(name=<env_name>, image="<registry_name>.azurecr.io/train_image")

cluster_name = <cluster_name>
cluster = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=cluster_name)
env.docker.base_image = "<registry_name>.azurecr.io/train_image"
env.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
dc = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)

scr = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory="source",
                                script='go.py',
                                compute_target=cluster,
                                environment=env,
                                docker_runtime_config=dc)


experiment_name = <experiment_name>
experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name=experiment_name)
run = experiment.submit(scr)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

"""
here's what's in my go.py file, it's just a script to run the train.py file in my container:

import subprocess

subproccess.run("python train.py")
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work !

I know it's not the cleanest code, i'm a beginner, but here's the working code if anyone is interested:

```
import os
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, Environment, ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute_target import ComputeTargetException
from azureml.core.container_registry import ContainerRegistry

ws = Workspace.from_config()

cluster_name = <cluster_name>
compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=cluster_name)

from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration

acr_name = <rregistry_name>
image_name = <image_name>
image_version = <img_version>

custom_env = Environment("custom_env")


custom_env.docker.base_image = None
custom_env.docker.base_dockerfile = None

acr = ContainerRegistry()
acr.address = f"{acr_name}.azurecr.io"
acr.username = <ACR_ADMIN_USERNAME> 
acr.password = <ACR_ADMIN_PASSWORD>

docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)
custom_env.docker.base_image_registry = acr


custom_env.docker.base_image = f"{acr_name}.azurecr.io/{image_name}:{image_version}"

custom_env.python.user_managed_dependencies = True

experiment_name = <exp_name>
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name=experiment_name)

# You need to create a dummy_train.py file on your local machine (will not be executed, mine is empty) the real one is located in your image (in ACR)

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.',
                      script='dummy_train.py',
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=custom_env,
                                            docker_runtime_config=docker_config)

run = exp.submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, how is your docker file structured?